# Match all words except a specific few for substitution purposes, math expression use case

Tags: python, regex

In the string

```
x='(var1 * 1.3e4 + abc)/log(blabla+2E3)'
```

I would like to substitute `var1`, `abc`, and `blabla` with `'1'`, say to pass into `ast` and see if this is a proper expression. **I don't want to touch** `log` or `e` or `E`. Of course there are other things I may want to skip, like `sin`.

Currently I'm using something like

```
for match in re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+',x):
    if match.startswith('log') or match.lower()=='e': continue
    x = x.replace(string,'1')
```

The log can come in a few flavors, hence `startswith` - obviously won't work for any case. **I would prefer to use** `re.sub` in one go.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get a proper expression parser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: @Pavel If I understand that correctly, that refers to 'numerical strings', as in, no 'abc' in the string. This is not optional, and the substitution is not just '1' in my actual use case, but real user variables. I do not won't to substitute anything in until I'm sure the expression is valid and all variables are recognized from a given set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/bWaKMk/3)

```
\b(?!(?:[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?|log|sin|cos)\b)\w+\b
```

#### Usage

Create an array of exceptions (as shown below) and join the list on `|`. Also, note that `re.escape` isn't always necessary, but I figured I'd show it to demonstrate how you would create this joined list with normal strings and regular expressions (in case that's what you need to do).

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/dRSRzT)

```
import re

exceptions = [
    re.escape("log"),
    re.escape("sin"),
    re.escape("cos"),
    r"[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?"
]

s = "(var1 * 1.3e4 + abc)/log(blabla+2E3)*1.2E+23"
r = r"\b(?!(?:" + "|".join(exceptions) + r")\b)\w+\b"

print re.sub(r, "1", s, 0, re.I)
```

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?!(?:stuff here)\b)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

  - `(?:stuff here)` This contains the joined list of exceptions such as `log`, `sin`, `cos`, or numbers (`[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?`), etc.
- `\w+` Match one or more word characters
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary

Comment: Very impressive, and thoroughly explained. Easy to scale. Note though `e` may be a capital, and maybe followed by a sign. Better use `e[^\w]` in the exception list. Also, no need for a `+` there.

Comment: @kabanus are `log` and `sin` case insensitive as well? Basically, is everything case insensitive?

Comment: Might as well make them if you're at it. That would be most flexible - probably just a `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: I already said I think the answer is very good, and you made it better. The only thing I have to add is that the exception`r"\d+(?:e\d+)?"` will fail on `1.2E+23`, which is valid. You can just add a `[+-]?` before the `\d`, and remove unneeded `+` at the end (one is enough for check).

Comment: @kabanus please see new update. I changed the number portion of the regex.

Comment: Are you sure `\de[+-]?\d` isn't enough to verify a valid exponential? You don't really care about catching **all** of it, just skip the `e`.

Comment: @kabanus *technically* yes. But if you want to ensure the full number format is captured as a whole (i.e. `1.2E+23` instead of `1` and `2E+23)

Comment: @kabanus actually your regex doesn't capture numbers without `e` in them. I would suggest using the new regex I posted above as it works with decimal places and with `e`